# Listview bound via ElementName stays empty

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, elementname

I'm stuck again at some data-binding issue. 
This time I want to bind a `ListView` to the `SelectedItem` of a `GridView`. I already suceed with this type of data-binding but now my `ListView`, which should show some details about my selected item in my `GridView` just stays empty. There are no items in it although they should exist.
The `GridView` binds just fine at the property in my `MainViewModel`.
Substituting the `ElementName` attribute with `x:Resouces` doesn't seem to be an option, because it doesn't work either.

The source view:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridViewOrderYears" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCustOrders, Mode=TwoWay}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="316" 
          Height="63" 
          Margin="657,316,0,0"
          SelectionMode="Single">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Aquamarine">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" FontSize="20"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderCount}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

this View doesnt bind:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="231" 
          Margin="657,401,0,0" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="316"
          DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=gridViewOrderYears}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DoneOrders.Order_Date, ElementName=gridViewOrderYears}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`SelectedCustOrders` porperty is an `IList<OrderYears>`.

`OrderYears` is following data value object defined in my `MainViewModel`:

```
public class OrderYears
    {
        public int? Year { get; set; }
        public IList<Orders> DoneOrders { get; set; }
        public int OrderCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.
After hours of trial-and-error finally substituting `DataContext` with `ItemsSource` did the trick... 
Sometimes things are easier than you think :)

Comment: Man, you just beat me to it! I came here to suggest you just that. I'm glad that you could solve it, it feels good when you get it on your own ;-) Thank you for the upvote!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the ListView binding, because you try to bind to a property named "Orders", which does not exist in the OrderYears object. You have a property named DoneOrders which you can bind to (don't confuse the property name with the type of elements inside the list!), but if you bind a TextBlock to a IList you will just get the guid for the IList object.

Try something like this, replacing you ListView with a ListBox (which is enough for what you are trying to do here):

```
 <ListBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=gridViewOrderYears, 
                                Path=SelectedItem.DoneOrders}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Order_Date"/>
```

There is no need to create a template, the items inside the ListBox will be displayed like a TextBlock. Note that you can benefit from binding to nested properties like MainProperty.SubProperty.

Let me know if this was helpful, bindings can be such a headache when you are starting...

Comment: actually that was a mistake I made when I copied it to SO. It WAS named `Orders` but I changed the name, so that I will not confuse it. I will edit my post to the correct names. The template was a placeholder, because I wanted to show more then just `Order_Date`. Maybe the `ListView` isn't the problem itself, since changing it to your `ListBox` example didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Of course, the problem is not about ListBox/ListView, they are practically the same and what is not working is the binding. Please post the correction and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: Well, I've tried many things till now but the code above is still what I stick to (with the corrected name I already edited ofc). I noticed that binding a TextBlock like the one I'm using in my data template alone does bind correctly. Just like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DoneOrders, Elementname=grid...}" />`

Comment: Finally got it. I will post it soon. Easier then I thought... well, I'm really thankful for your help, though :)